# how to display the reference of FK ID in JTable (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

[image]Hi,

I have a multiple tables in my Database and some of those tables have relationship with my employee_details table, and now, I want to display the records from the employee_details table to my JTable. But I want the FK ID string valued instead of the actual ID.

> public void DBTable(){

```
    try {
        String InsertToTable = "Select EmpDetails_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Position_ID, Department_ID, "
                + "Office_Location_ID, Employee_Status, Office_Number, Mobile_Number, Email_Address, Remarks, Image From employee_details";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(InsertToTable);
        rs= pst.executeQuery();
        EmpDBTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Employee_Details.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean instead of Departman_ID, You want to display Departman's Name ?

Comment: Exactly! I need to show the department name instead of FK ID.

Comment: Do you have example code for your Jtable?

Comment: That is the SQL query from the employee_details table. I have three FK fields inside the that tabe and one of them is the Department.

Comment: Only thing I can think of at the moment is to create a view in database. This view is made up of multiple joins connecting employee_details table with departmant, position and office_location tables. Modify the view's column list to reflect Departman's Name then Connect the Jtable to this view.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe better way, is to modify your sql.                                          "Select EmpDetails_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Position_ID, employee_details.Department_ID,department.Department_Name "
+ "Office_Location_ID, Employee_Status, Office_Number, Mobile_Number, Email_Address, Remarks, Image From employee_details inner join department on employee_details.Department_ID = department.Department_ID";

Comment: I will update you back after I tried this solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and all the other type of join but still didn't work.

Comment: Is there somewhere in code where you specifically define model's fields?

Comment: Model's fields? what do you mean by that? I'm sorry because I'm new to java, I'm not familiar with all the terms.

Comment: is "EmpDBTable" the JTable  in your code ?

Comment: EmpDBTable is the name of my jTable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195000/discussion-between-haider-abdullah-and-antiqtech).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified an example code I've found online. I downloaded rs2xml.jar to get "DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)". I created your tables employee_details and department in my local sql server. I used SQL Join example I gave you and was able to get that extra column on JTable. Please compare this example with your own code.  In this code, I get the following result: 
[image]

Here is the code (modified from an online example):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class SearchResult {
JFrame frame, frame1; 
JPanel panel;
static JTable table;

String driverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=DESKTOP-8QFTIP4;databaseName=deneme;user=sa;password=******";
String userName = "sa";
String password = "*****";    

public void createUI()
{
    showTableData();
} 
public void showTableData()
{

    frame1 = new JFrame("Database Search Result");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    table = new JTable(); 
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); 
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        System.out.println("conn before");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        System.out.println("conn after");
        String sql ="Select EmpDetails_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Position_ID, "
                + " employee_details.Department_ID,department.Department_Name , Office_Location_ID, Employee_Status, "
                + " Office_Number, Mobile_Number, Email_Address, Remarks, Image "
                + " From employee_details inner join department on employee_details.Department_ID = department.Department_ID";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println("about to execute");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        int i =0;
        System.out.println("after to execute"); 
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(),"Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    frame1.add(scroll);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setSize(400,300);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
    sr.createUI();
}
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out, and I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain this to me `employee_details.Department_ID,department.Department_Name` is the Department_ID is the FK in your employee_details table and Department_Name is form your department table?

Comment: Yes.  Department_ID from employee_details table and  Department_Name  from department table is selected in the query.  table_name.field_name is a good way to define what you want to get in sql queries.

Comment: `department.Department_ID`is the Department_ID is the one in your employee-details table or in the department table.

Comment: it is the one employee-details table but since we are "inner join"ing  tables on Department_ID, it doesn't matter which table it is from. Both will have the same value. employee_details.Department_ID=department.Department_ID

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. If you have any further questions, send me a message

Comment: Thank you how can I reach you via message.

Comment: You can use https://chat.stackoverflow.com open chat room and invite me to the room.

Comment: I'm in the java chat room I couldn't find the invite.